# TCP via TETRAprotocol

Tags: java, android, http, tcp

There is a device that works on Android 6. It does not have TCP, there is only a [TETRA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrestrial_Trunked_Radio) communication channel.

There works one application that transmits information via the TETRA channel. Since there is no TCP on the device, normal applications (for example, Skype) do not work. Is it possible to create some kind of gateway (for example, programmatically) so that all TCP requests, like sent through TETRA to endPoint?

Or, for example, create an application (proxy) that intercepts all tcp requests and sends a request to the BS using the TETRA protocol and the base station reads this request and there is already running a tcp request for some endPoint (for example, a Skype server), and the response back via TETRA on the device, our proxy application reads the response and interprets it in the TCP response.

I do not quite understand this, maybe I messed up a lot. Tell me, please, is this possible? How?

Comment: Interest Ask! Only I have no answer